# Coldfusion Method Level scope definition

Tags: coldfusion

What is be the best way to define method level variables scope?

Some ColdFusion documents say it should be done like this:

```
 <cfset Var testVariable = "this is a local variable">
```

But others, do it like this:

```
<cfset LOCAL = StructNew() />
<cfset LOCAL.testVariable  = StructNew() />
```

Which way is better?

Comment: Actually this is not an answer, but you'll get more information [here](http://www.isummation.com/blog/work-around-coldfusion-local-scope/) that I dig about local scope.

Comment: It's worth noting your second example should be:
<cfset var local = structNew() />

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either will work.

In CF9 (and I assume 10) var local = structNew() is unnecessary (though harmless and makes your code backward compatible) as there is within each function a local scope that contains any locally scoped values.  Also with CF8 and earlier these variables will need to be the first thing declared in a function.

So to specifically answer your question I prefer the var local = structNew() (or just var local={}) because:

- It means that locally scoped variables are obviously such (var
  scoping issues can be a pain to debug).
- You can dump or examine the
  local "scope" in cf 8.

Comment: Small clarification, in CF9 you no longer need the `var` keyword. But you must still use the `local` prefix to place variables in the function local scope ie `<cfset Local.testVariable = "..">`. Also, for debugging in CF8 you can use the undocumented `getPageContext().getActiveFunctionLocalScope()` method to dump the function local variables. Though admittedly `var local = {}` is more kosher :)